# SQL query to replace H1 tags with H2 in specific post type and field

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to replace H1 tags in WordPress post content with H2 via phpmyadmin, and though my query seems to find results on simulation, when running it's not changing what I need.

I need to filter this by post type and field so it only affects the content (not title) of the standard WP post type.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (  post_content,  'h1',  'h2') 
WHERE (post_type = 'post') ;
```

Comment: Note that all three string arguments passed to the REPLACE() method are case-sensitive. `h1` and `H1` are not the same. [Example](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-the-replace-function-in-mysql)

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by not changing what you need! We do not see the underlying data, nor the output of your script, nor the expected results.

Comment: @Shadow Well it seems to be changing 39 rows, but they don't appear to be the h1 tags in the post content. I can't seem to edit the question to include example content and it's too long to post in a comment

Answer (score 0):

The typical main headers of Wordpress posts are *not* saved with an `h1` tag in the database - the header text (i.e. what you define as the *title* in the WP editor) is "inserted" into `h1` elements when the HTML code is created on page load. Their being `h1` elements is defined in template files, for example `post.php` or `index.php`, or actually even `header.php` (which often contains the main header and the navbar), depending on the theme you use.

So your choices are either to edit the code in those template files accordingly, or create a script (javascript or jQuery) which converts the `h1` elements to `h2` on load.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. It's not the titles I need to change, it's the H1s in the post_content field. That content IS stored because I can see it via the database and find H1s in there.